# Angular2 @Input to a property with get/set

Tags: angular

I have an Angular2 component in that component it currently has a bunch fields that have @Input() applied before them to allow binding to that property, i.e.

```
@Input() allowDay: boolean;
```

What I would like to do is actually bind to a property with get/set, so that I can do some other logic in the setter, something like the following

```
_allowDay: boolean;
get allowDay(): boolean {
    return this._allowDay;
}
set allowDay(value: boolean) {
     this._allowDay = value;
     this.updatePeriodTypes();
}
```

how would I do this in Angular2?

Based on Thierry Templier suggestion I changed it to, but that throws the error Can't bind to 'allowDay' since it isn't a known native property :

```
//@Input() allowDay: boolean;
_allowDay: boolean;
get allowDay(): boolean {
    return this._allowDay;
}
@Input('allowDay') set allowDay(value: boolean) {
    this._allowDay = value;
    this.updatePeriodTypes();
}
```

Comment: How and where to do you bind to `[allowDay]="....". If the field (setter) name and the property name you want to use for binding are the same, you can omit the parameter for `@Input(...)`.

Comment: I would be curious to see how yo set up your unit test if you went the route of using get set as shown in the accepted answer.

Comment: Whatever you end up doing make sure to put a breakpoint, or debug statement, or counter inside your setter to make sure it is only firing once as expected. I just found mine was being updated for every change detection run causing horrible performance and quirky behavior.

Answer (score 479, accepted):

You could set the `@Input` on the setter directly, as described below:

```js
_allowDay: boolean;
get allowDay(): boolean {
    return this._allowDay;
}
@Input() set allowDay(value: boolean) {
    this._allowDay = value;
    this.updatePeriodTypes();
}
```

See this Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/6miSutgTe9sfEMCb8N4p?p=preview.

Comment: I get the following error 
Can't bind to 'allowDay' since it isn't a known native property.  See updated question for exactly what I changed the code to

Comment: Are you sure? It works for me. I added a plunkr. Perhaps you forgot to add the directive into the `directives` attribute of the component where you want to use it... I updated my answer.

Comment: Can these inputs be optional?  For example, if it wasn't using get or set I could use @Input() allowDay?: boolean

Comment: This is a bad idea because if you use the setter, ngOnChanges doesn't fire.

Comment: [On angular Fundamentals pages](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter)

Comment: *WARNING*: The `setter` will **NOT** be triggered by mutations to values which are passed by reference (i.e. pushing to an array, mutating an object, etc.). You would need to replace the whole value being passed as an `Input` for the `setter` to trigger again.

Comment: @user2867288 : Nope, it does trigger `ngOnChanges()` .Refer https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzwusa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Let me clarify my statement. If you call the setter from inside the component, ngOnChanges() does not fire. E.G. `this.allowDay = true` does not fire ngOnChanges().

Comment: Yes, @ Thierry Templier : `@Input('[var_name'])` will not be recognized by a parent which has, on the HTML this input.It's a string - Angular doesn't read strings... `Can't bind to '[var_name]' since it isn't a known property of '<some-parent />'`

Comment: ES Lint won't allow this eslint.org/docs/rules/no-underscore-dangle

Answer (score 99):

If you are mainly interested in implementing **logic to the setter only**:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

// [...]

export class MyClass implements OnChanges {
  @Input() allowDay: boolean;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if(changes['allowDay']) {
      this.updatePeriodTypes();
    }
  }
}
```

The import of `SimpleChanges` is not needed if it doesn't matter which input property was changed or if you have only one input property.

[Angular Doc: OnChanges](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-class.html)

**otherwise:**

```js
private _allowDay: boolean;

@Input() set allowDay(value: boolean) {
  this._allowDay = value;
  this.updatePeriodTypes();
}
get allowDay(): boolean {
  // other logic
  return this._allowDay;
}
```

Comment: Just curious, is there any benefit for using ngOnChanges vs not using the set property if you are only interested on a setter logic?

Comment: There is no difference in "using ngOnChanges vs not using set"... ;) Joking aside: One benefit is, if your component has multiple `@Input` properties and you want to call a routine when any of them has changed. So less code needed.

Comment: Ups, had a typo hehe. But ok, thought it might had more relevance. Thanks for the answer tho :)

Comment: @MA-Maddin I suppose you could also set a debounced observable if you were expecting multiple changes all at the same time that would each result in a routine needing to be run.

Comment: Heads up... if your input type is an Interface, OnChanges does not catch attribute value changes.

Comment: @dvdmn Yes, since the property's reference stays the same in such case. That's by design and the same in every language, I would say. Re-assigning the value will trigger, as also mentioned in [Nickofthyme's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653678/angular2-input-to-a-property-with-get-set/40764091?noredirect=1#comment93559361_36653734)

Comment: @MartinSchneider, you are right... but if the logic of Change Detection can detect a value change for a boolean type, it is expected behavior that it would detect a "value change" on an attribute.
I think using Object.is() is the wrong choice for change detection as it is failing in this case.

Comment: NgOnChanges will get called a lot. Better off using setters if you only need access to that one variable

Answer (score 14):

@Paul Cavacas, I had the same issue and I solved by setting the `Input()` decorator above the getter.

```
  @Input('allowDays')
  get in(): any {
    return this._allowDays;
  }

  //@Input('allowDays')
  // not working
  set in(val) {
    console.log('allowDays = '+val);
    this._allowDays = val;
  }
```

See this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/6miSutgTe9sfEMCb8N4p?p=preview

Comment: This bug got me crazy, I finally found that you should define the Input() first (getter or setter but the input decorator must go first)

Comment: Here's other reference that may help [https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5477](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5477)

Answer (score 2):

**In angular v16.1.0-next.3**

We can use transform property on inputs. If an input has a transform function, any values set through the template will be passed through the function before being assigned to the directive instance.

The example from above can be rewritten to the following:

```
@Input({ transform: booleanAttribute }) allowDay = false;
```

**[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ziahci?file=src%2Ftodo.cmp.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

Updated accepted answer to angular 7.0.1 on stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inputsetter?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

`directives` are no more in Component decorator options. So I have provided sub directive to app module.