# Two way binding between components in angular 2-4

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

I would like the child component value to be bound to the parent component. How to accomplish this when `@Input()` and `[(ngModel)]` are not enough ?

[here is a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qPFxZRcWINPse5F2TVaP?p=preview)

Comment: Do you mean you want to access child component methods and variables in parent component?

Comment: In fact I would like the changes inside child component to affect the variable value in the parent.

Comment: you can use a get set on your Input() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653678/angular2-input-to-a-property-with-get-set

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you have to set `@Output` also and change the component like

```
export class CounterComponent {

  @Output('initoChange') emitter: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Input('inito') set setInitoValue(value) {
      this.count = value;
  }
  count: number = 0;

  increment() {
    this.count++;
    this.emitter.emit(this.count);
  }

  decrement() {
    this.count--;
    this.emitter.emit(this.count);
  }

}
```

Here is the link to [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YLSpE9p0AzJUiqgw7FcF?p=preview) , please have a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
You mean the `@Output` key must be (`'[var]Change'`) thus `'intoChange'`, right?

Comment: Made a small change in the plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/99qo5tzBkUAc0rZYAorQ?p=preview) Changes directly in the child component input are also rendered.

Answer (score 8):

You can make two-way data binding like following:

```
@Component({

selector: 'app-sizer',
  template: `
  <div>
    <button (click)="dec()" title="smaller">-</button>
    <button (click)="inc()" title="bigger">+</button>
    <label [style.font-size.px]="size">FontSize: {{size}}px</label>
  </div>`
})
export class SizerComponent {
  @Input()  size: number | string;
  @Output() sizeChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  dec() { this.resize(-1); }
  inc() { this.resize(+1); }

  resize(delta: number) {
    this.size = Math.min(40, Math.max(8, +this.size + delta));
    this.sizeChange.emit(this.size);
  }
}
```

And in template of parent component make two-way binding to `size` like following:

```
<app-sizer [(size)]="fontSizePx"></app-sizer>
<div [style.font-size.px]="fontSizePx">Resizable Text</div>
```

It (two-way binding) is just a syntax sugar for property binding, so it is equivalent to:

```
<app-sizer [size]="fontSizePx" (sizeChange)="fontSizePx=$event"></app-sizer>
```

`[(prop)]` syntax using is possible when the `prop` has `Input` property called `prop` and event (`Output` property) that has a name `propChange`.

Code is from angular docs for more information navigate to this address: 
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---

Comment: using angular 6, I am getting the array of images from http request and pushing into array and displaying using ngfor . for the first set it works and after the page scroll dynamic fetching of images not working. Fetching of text is working dynamically on scroll also  Can you help me .

Answer (score 0):

use `@Output()` 
for example

```
@Output() event: EventEmitter<Type> = new EventEmitter();
```

send data via `emit` function

```
send(): void {
  this.event.emit(data);
}
```

read more about [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)