# Angular listen for value change of a number property (NOT @Input) with - ngDoCheck?

Tags: angular, observable, listener, parent-child, ngonchanges

I have a FormGroup array of rates namely `ratesMainArray` being `@Input` from a parent to my child component. I am filtering it in `ngOnChanges` by its `special` or `normal` key value every time its length in the parent component changes and storing the `length` value of the filtered array in two local properties, `specialRates` and `normalRates` which are of course of type `number`.
I need to listen to that length value changes, but `ngOnChanges` only reacts to the parent array changes. 
I have started using `ngDoCheck` which actually detects the filtered arrays value changes, but I am receiving the error `Error trying to diff '2'. Only maps and objects are allowed` when I try to react to the filtered array length.

This is a simplified version of the code:

```
...
@Input() ratesMainArray: FormGroup[];
specialRates: number;
normalRates: number;
differ: any;

constructor(private differs: KeyValueDiffers) {
    this.differ = differs.find({}).create();
  }

ngDoCheck() {
    const changes = this.differ.diff(this.specialRates);
      if (changes) {
         changes.forEachAddedItem(r => console.log('added ' + r.currentValue));
                   }
}

async ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    if ((this.ratesMainArray && this.ratesMainArray.length) 
         && (changes && changes.ratesMainArray && changes.ratesMainArray.currentValue.length)) {

this.specialRates= this.ratesMainArray.filter(t => t.controls.isSpecialRate.value === true).length;
this.normalRates= this.ratesMainArray.filter(t => t.controls.isSpecialRate.value === false).length;

}

// ideally, I would like to do something like this:
// if (this.specialRates.valueChanges or changes.specialRates.currentValue) {
// do somthing
// } else {
// do something else
// }

}
```

I don't necessarily need to use `ngDoCheck`, but since it was detecting the filtered array change I thought it was the way to go. Just for clarity, I also tried using `private cd: ChangeDetectorRef` and `this.cd.detectChanges();` without luck before trying `ngDoCheck`.

Thanks for you help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'set' to analyze the data that you receives in the @Input()

```
specialRates: number;
normalRates: number;
differ: any;
private _ratesMainArray: FormGroup[];
get ratesMainArray(): FormGroup[] {
   return this._ratesMainArray;
}
@Input() set ratesMainArray(value: FormGroup[]){
    if(value) {
      this._ratesMainArray = value;
this.specialRates= this.ratesMainArray.filter(t => t.controls.isSpecialRate.value === true).length;
this.normalRates= this.ratesMainArray.filter(t => t.controls.isSpecialRate.value === false).length;
    }
}

constructor(private differs: KeyValueDiffers) {
   this.differ = differs.find({}).create();
}
```

Here you have another example of get/set in @Input():
[Angular2 @Input to a property with get/set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653678/angular2-input-to-a-property-with-get-set/40764091)

Comment: Hi, and thanks for helping. I edited my code with `set` and `get`, now I'm doing my filtering  in the `@Input()` as you pointed out but still I am not able to detect changes to them in `ngOnChanges` or `ngDoCheck`. I mean, am I supposed to?

Comment: No, now every time that the @Input() changes, you have the new values for your properties. I have just updated my answer

Comment: I can still only see the `simpleChanges` related to the length of my `ratesMainArray` unfortunately... and `ngDoCheck` shows the same `[ object Object ]`.