# Detect Input() Value Change Inside Child (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

I just need to update child component when Input value changes , the child component has some input parameters which set some local variables inside ngInit() but the issue is the parent when change the input parameters the child does not update because ngInit() only trigger once it is initialize.

**Inside Parent**

```
<app-site-parameter-tbl *ngIf="siteTbl==true" [siteParameterTDataSet]="siteParameterDataSet" [siteParameterTGridColumns]="siteParameterColumns" [siteParameterFoot]="siteParameterFooter" [siteParameterT]="siteParameterTbl" [model]="siteModel" [bckColor]="this.tabBackColor"></app-site-parameter-tbl>
```

On some trigger events the parent changes these properties (as input of child)

**Parent Ts**

```
method(ds, columns, footer) {

    this.siteParameterDataSet = ds;
    this.siteParameterColumns = columns;
    this.siteParameterFooter = footer;
}
```

This hit only once even after changing input values

**Child ts**

```
@Input() siteParameterT: boolean;
@Input() model: SiteModel;
@Input() siteParameterFoot: [];
@Input() siteParameterTGridColumns: [];
@Input() siteParameterTDataSet: any;

ngOnInit() {
    debugger;
    //setting local variables then they will render inside html

    this.siteParameter = this.siteParameterT;
    this.site = this.model;
    this.foot = this.siteParameterFoot;
    this.dataSet = this.siteParameterTDataSet;
}
```

Please help , if I can use Input properties directly inside html then how come can i make changes to it?
Help me know how to notify when Input changes?

Comment: Do this assignment inside `ngOnChanges`.

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI Look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/36653734/7321113

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI you can try to use ChangeDetectionStrategy on push in this scenario:
https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

Comment: thank you @Abhishek ngOnChanges solved my problem ,also its one stop solution i can check property using switch then update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hook into [ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence) instead:

*example usage*

```
  @Input() employee: Employee

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    /** Fire any time employee changes */
    if (changes.employee && changes.employee.currentValue) {
      this.formGroup.patchValue(this.employee)
    }
  }
```

---

There's also a [decorator method](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/creatively-decouple-ngonchanges-fab95395cc6e). Though note the TypeScript decorator is experimental.

Answer (score 3):

Try using setters on the `@Input`:

```
@Input('siteParameterT')
set siteParameterT(value: boolean) {
    this.siteParameter = value
}
```

also, you can use [ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges)

Comment: thank you very much for your time , but ngOnChanges worked fine. vote up..thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the functionality using `ngOnChanges`.

```
 public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.siteParameter = changes.siteParameter;
    etc.,
  }
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time , but ngOnChanges worked fine. vote up..thanks again