# How to set default value for Input Angular?

Tags: angular

I have Input in component:

```
  @Input() applicant: Applicant;

interface Applicant {
   applicant: ApplicantItem,
   representative: Representative
}
```

Template is:

```
<div *ngIf="applicant.representative.type></div>
```

Problem is if `applicant` has no object `representative` it falls.

How to set default value if there is no `representative`?

Like this:

```
@Input() applicant: Applicant = <Applicant>{};
```

I need to have `representative` with `type` always.

Also how to avoid error here:

```
applicant.representative = adapt(applicant.representative);
```

Here `applicant.representative` should be default object `{ representative: {type:` }}`

Comment: You can use null propagation like this : `<div *ngIf="applicant?.representative?.type></div>`

Comment: I dont like this syntax

Comment: Then you can use [get/set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653678/angular2-input-to-a-property-with-get-set) for your input. In the getter check the value if it is set, if not update it.

Comment: How to to that in level upper? Here `this.applicants.map((applicant) => {
this.representativeAdapter.adapt(applicant.representative); }`

Comment: Simple: `@Input() applicant: Applicant={applicant:null,representative:{type:null}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hai you can try to set the value in ngOnInit. once the ngOnInIt is called the value for the
`applicant` will be set if any provided by the parent component.

Here check if the value is undefined and if so set a default

```
@Input() applicant: Applicant;

ngOnInIt() {
    if (!this.applicant) {
      this.applicant = {
          // ur defaults here
      };
}
```

if you want to always pass proper values to children components from parent then

```
this.applicants.map((applicant) => {
     if (!applicant || !applicant.representative) {
      applicant = {
        // your defaults here
      };
      this.representativeAdapter.adapt(applicant.representative);
      ...
```

Comment: How to do that here: `this.applicants.map((applicant) => { this.representativeAdapter.adapt(applicant.representative); }`?

Comment: what is `representativeAdapter` here, where did this applicants array come from. is this in the parent component?

Comment: This is method, that accepts `applicant.representative` but if no `representative` it falls

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@Input() applicant = function(applicant : Applicant  = {applicant:null, representative:nul}){
    console.log(applicant)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by specifying setter and getter for your @Input:

```
@Input() 
set applicant(applicant: Applicant) {
    this._applicant = applicant || { applicant: null, representative: null };
}
get applicant(): Applicant {
    return this._applicant;
}

private _applicant: Applicant;
```

Answer (score 0):

When we use class then

```
@Input() applicant: Applicant = new Applicant();
```

When we use interface then:

```
@Input() applicant: Applicant = {} as Applicant;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to set a configuration object with defaults.

- The property binding can receive an object with optional properties.
- Name the applicant _applicant in your code to indicate this value should not be accessed
- In your code use a getter called applicant to access the value
- In the getter set up some defaults
- Merge the defaults with the provided values

**code**

```
@Input('applicant') _applicant: {applicant?: ApplicantItem, representative?: Representative }
public get applicant(): {applicant: ApplicantItem, representative: Representative } {
  const defaults = {
    applicant: new ApplicantItem(),
    representative: new Representative()
  }

  return {...defaults, ...this._applicant}
}
```