# @Input setter not updating view data

Tags: angular

In my angular 6 application, I am getting data from store selector which in turn gets data from API using effect, and from a parent, I injecting that data as an async pipe in child component as below:

```
<chart-data 
[tableData]="data | async">
>
```

child component implementation :

```
  public chartData: any[];
  // input setter
 @Input() set tableData(
    value: tableData[];
  ) {
    if (value.length > 0) {
      this.chartData = value;
    }
  }
```

Child component template

```
{{tableData | json}}
<section class="chart-container" *ngIf="chartData?.length > 0">
    <div>
     {{chartData| json}}
    </div>
    </section>
```

If I print JSON response, data is coming before I check the length here but it does not print the data after inside if condition, Is that because I use the same object or do I need to create a copy before I render it to the template?

Comment: I think you should replace `tableData` with `chartData` in your child component template, or create a getter to retrieve the `chartData` as `tableData`, as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36653734/8712609).

Comment: sorry it was a typo i modified the code above, but even it does not work

Comment: You should replace all `tableData` with `chartData` in your child component template.

Comment: oh sorry that was typo too, I am sorry, but even it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. I don't use setters with @Input decorators.  Maybe try tapping into the ngOnChanges lifecycle hook instead.

```
@Input tableData;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.tableData?.length) {
        this.chartData = this.tableData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the object is an array, you need to change the reference of the array in order to retrigger the setter.