# Call a method after assigning multiple property values in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular component with two input properties. I would like to call a method when both properties are set, is there any event I can use?

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  _product: Product;
  @Input() set product(value: Product) {
      _product = value;
  }
  
  _attributeType: any;
  @Input() set attributeType(value: any) {
      _attributeType = value; 
      this.doSomeWorkWhenBothProductAndAttributeTypeAreSet();
  }
 
  doSomeWorkWhenBothProductAndAttributeTypeAreSet() {
  }
}
```

In the above code sample, I would like to call doSomeWorkWhenBothProductAndAttributeTypeAreSet() when product and attribute type have been assigned. I tried calling the method after setting the second property but sometimes the product takes longer to assign so does not work as expected.

Comment: There is a "bad"/hacky way. Put a timeout  of something like 100 or 200ms on doSomeWorkWhenBothProductAndAttributeTypeAreSet. That way you know that it will run after _attributeType and _product are set

Comment: Is there any better way to do this? :) worried I will keep increasing this timeout in future

Comment: Take a look of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40764091/5468463

Comment: Instead of defining a setter, use ngOnChanges lifeCycle hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement `OnChanges` interface in order to check changes on input attributes, and add some logic depending on that.

```js
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() set product(value: Product) {
      _product = value;
  }
  
  _attributeType: any;
  @Input() set attributeType(value: any) {
      _attributeType = value; 
  }
 
  ngOnChanges(simpleChange: SimpleChanges) {
    if (this._attributeType && this._product) {
      this.doSomeWorkWhenBothProductAndAttributeTypeAreSet();
    }

    // or check simpleChange to retrieve some informations :
    // - new value
    // - previous value
  }

  doSomeWorkWhenBothProductAndAttributeTypeAreSet() {
  }
}
```

More details on [official docs](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)

Answer (score 1):

Angular has some [lyfecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) that can be used to execute parts of logic only in determinate moments, this is a list of every lifecycle hook a component has:

- `ngOnChanges()`
- `ngOnInit()`
- `ngDoCheck()`
- `ngAfterContentInit()`
- `ngAfterContentChecked()`
- `ngAfterViewInit()`
- `ngAfterViewChecked()`
- `ngOnDestroy()`

Now, angular calls `ngOnChanges` the first time before the `ngOnInit` to let you access the `@Input()` variables with their values on init. Said that you have two main ways of achieving your goal:

1. By using `ngOnChanges()`:

```
public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    // you can check here if your props are set and if so call your method
    console.log(changes['YOUR_PROP'].currentValue);
}
```

Note that this method will be called on every @Input() prop update

2. By directly using `ngOnInit()`:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    // here you can access your props since angular has called onChanges before and has already initialized them
}
```