# how to initialize @Input property

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

In my angular application, i pass an object `todo` down to a child component via Input, which contains an array of strings at `todo.tags`. I now want to modify this array and therefore snap a copy of it and assign to a new variable like this:

```
@Input() todo: ITodos
public tags: Array<string> = [...this.todo.tags]
```

But i get the Error "property is used before initialization" which makes sense because i only declare `todo` . But i dont know how or for what i should initialize an Input, because the value *is* the input

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to init tags in getter for input like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653678/angular2-input-to-a-property-with-get-set).

In case you are using RxJs in your project - you can pass an Observable, subscribe on it in the OnInit method and update tags on subscription firing.

```js
@Input() todo: Observable<ITodos> = null;
public tags: Array<string> = null;

this.todo.pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
         .subscribe(value => this.tags = [...value.tags]);
```

P.s. @ngneat/until-destroy is used for subscription clean up in the example